# Is there a jquery event that fires when a new node is inserted into the dom?

Tags: jquery, html

Is there an event jquery fires on a dom element when it is inserted into the dom?

E.g. lets say I load some content via ajax and add it to the DOM and in some other piece of javascript I could add an event using .live() so that when an event matching a specific selector is added to the DOM the event fires on said element. Similar to $(document).ready() but on content that is added to the DOM dynamically.

What I am dreaming of:

```
$('.myClass').live('ready', function() {
    alert('.myClass added to dom');
});
```

If jquery doesn't support such a thing then is there another way I could achieve this functionality without modifying the code that actually does the initial dom manipulation?

Comment: Hello, to do this, you need to trigger the insert in your other piece of Javascript. `$("<div class='myClass'>").appendTo(document.body).trigger("ready");`

Comment: And if you happen to be attaching a jQuery UI widget to your content at the same time you're adding it to the DOM, you can just listen to the `[widget]create` event. (See http://api.jqueryui.com/jQuery.widget/#event-create ; be mindful of widget event prefixes.)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The [`.livequery()` plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/livequery/) still serves this niche need, like this:

```
$('.myClass').livequery(function() {
  alert('.myClass added to dom');
});
```

If you pass it *just* a callback function like above, it'll run for each new element it finds, both initially and as they're added.  Inside the function `this` refers to the just-added element.

[`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) listens for events that bubble, so doesn't fit this "when elements are added" situation, in that respect, [`.livequery()`](http://plugins.jquery.com/livequery/) (the plugin) wasn't *completely* replaced by the addition of [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) to core, only the event bubbling portion (for the most part) was.

Comment: For those that are curious how livequery works, there are no setTimeout's or anything silly; livequery simply "proxies" the browser's DOM manipulation methods

Comment: Actually it *is* silly since it only short-circuits jQuery DOM-manipulation methods in order to execute some code when they're called. If the DOM is updated without using jQuery methods, it just won't work.

Comment: Plugin seems dead. For anyone looking at this now, take a look at [insertionQuery](https://github.com/naugtur/insertionQuery). Interesting library that uses CSS to detect new elements.

Answer (score 41):

> **deprecated**: as per @Meglio's comment below, the `DOMNodeInserted` event is deprecated, and will be removed from the web at some unkown time in the future. For the best results, start learning about the [MutationObserver API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).
>
> see @dain's answer [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12773757/29182).

If you bind the ['DOMNodeInserted' event](http://help.dottoro.com/ljmcxjla.php) to the document or body directly, it will get executed every time anything is inserted anywhere. If you want the callback to run only when a particular kind of element is added, you would be wise to use [delegated events](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events).

Usually, if you are adding a class of elements to the DOM you will be adding them to a common parent. So attach the event handler like this:

```
$('body').on('DOMNodeInserted', '#common-parent', function(e) {
  if ($(e.target).attr('class') === 'myClass') {
    console.log('hit');
  }
});
```

Basically the same answer as [Myke's above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12714512/29182), but since you are using a delegated event handler rather than a direct event handler, the code in there will be fired less often.

NOTE:

```
$('body').on('DOMNodeInserted', '.myClass', function(e) {
  console.log(e.target);
});
```

This seems to work too... but I don't know why.

Comment: This looks to be the best answer. I got it to work by targeting the document. example: `$(document).on('DOMNodeInserted', function(e) {
     if ($(e.target).children(":first").attr('class') === 'lpChatTextLink')
     {
      changeMessage();
     }
    });` This does actually loop through all though. Didn't test the above as much.

Comment: I would say this is certainly the best answer for modern browsers but support only goes back as far as IE9 so would still require a fallback.

Comment: Deprecated: This feature has been removed from the Web. Though some browsers may still support it, it is in the process of being dropped. Do not use it in old or new projects. Pages or Web apps using it may break at any time. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events  --- use MutationObservers instead: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Comment: @Meglio the working is "Use Mutation Observers instead _if possible_." (emphasis added). See also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver#Browser_compatibility

Comment: (BTW @Meglio I agree with you for sure, and will use this in future projects)

Comment: @Meglio I've updated my answer to reflect the state of the art.

Comment: This question is a good example of how fast and completely the web changes: two answers with 10+ votes, and another coming up!

Comment: This is much too simple and useable, we must deprecate it immediately!... Sometimes I hate the web.

Comment: It wasn’t "useable" at all on big DOM changes. It was deprecated because it performed poorly, in favor of an alternative that would solve this issue. Tip: if you don’t understand why something was deprecated, look for the reason *before* complaining about it.

Answer (score 24):

You can use `MutationObserver`; it’s supported by all browsers except Opera Mini: http://caniuse.com/#feat=mutationobserver

```
  var MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver || window.MozMutationObserver;
  var list = document.querySelector('ol');
 
  var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {  
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
      if (mutation.type === 'childList') {
        var list_values = [].slice.call(list.children)
            .map( function(node) { return node.innerHTML; })
            .filter( function(s) {
              if (s === '<br>') {
                return false;
              }
              else {
                return true;
              }
        });
        console.log(list_values);
      }
    });
  });
 
  observer.observe(list, {
    attributes: true, 
    childList: true, 
    characterData: true 
   });
```

See: https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/05/dom-mutationobserver-reacting-to-dom-changes-without-killing-browser-performance/

Also, here's the direct link the the API on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Answer (score 6):

There is no jQuery event, but there is a DOM event: DOMNodeInsertedIntoDocument. You can listen for DOM events using jQuery's on method. So:

```
$('.myClass').on('DOMNodeInsertedIntoDocument', function() {
  alert('myClass was inserted into the DOM');
}
```

This may be preferable to using liveQuery as that plugin is a bit stale (no updates for 2+ years, only promises support for jQuery 1.2.x).

Comment: I couldn't get this to work any way... any insights on how to make it work?

Comment: This don't work because you are attaching the event handler to the element before it is inserted into the dom, so the selector probably returns empty element set.

Another approach would be to use delegation, for example -- **
$(document.body).on('DOMNodeInsertedIntoDocument', '.myClass', function() {
  alert('myClass was inserted into the DOM');
}** --

But this don't work either, because DOMNodeInsertedIntoDocument does not bubbles up.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [insertionQuery](https://github.com/naugtur/insertionQuery). It's an interesting library that uses CSS to detect new elements. Because it uses CSS there's no performance hit and you get returned the actual elements matching the selector.

Comment: This is a very clever way of approaching the problem. Starring the GitHub repo for later.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that using "animation" as trigger works well. All you need is CSS code with empty keyframes and a class selector which applies this animation to the element. Then apply event listener for `animationend` and check if the animation that has occured was the one you wanted. This is done by checking `animationName`:

```js
$("").on('animationend', function (e) {
    if(e.originalEvent.animationName != "_load") return 
  // YOUR CODE ...
})
```

```css
@keyframes _load {
  from {
  }
  to {
  }
}
.load-trigger {
  animation-name: _load;
  animation-duration: 0.1ms;
}
```