# DOM callback for node creation

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jstree

I want a certain callback executed each time a div satisfying a certain selector is inserted into a DOM. I've poked around the DOM events documentation, and the closest event I've found to what I need is "load", but it doesn't quite work as I hope.

Ideally I want something along the lines of:

```
$(".myclass").live("load", function(){... do stuff to $(this) ...}
```

---

To give some context to what I'm doing:

I have an event on a webpage which creates new forms each time some button is clicked. Modifying that JS code is highly undesirable. I want to convert one of the fields in the form into jstree, so the only approach I was able to think of is to attach a callback for insertion-into-DOM-event and attach a jstree inside a func.

---

Update: I've found DOMNodeInserted, but apparently it's not supported in IE.

Comment: Check out this question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3900151/is-there-a-jquery-event-that-fires-when-a-new-node-is-inserted-into-the-dom

Comment: @BryanRoss,  thanks, liveQuery looks like almost exactly what I need, looking through it's source now -- can't quite figure out how it works.

Comment: @cheshire it works by polling the state of the DOM every period. Then tree walking the entire DOM and manually checking what has changed. i.e. it's slow as hell. Bonus: it works with jQuery 1.3 and is abandonware last time I looked.

Comment: Lol. yeah, that's what I thought. Thanks though :P

Comment: @cheshire you know the real answer is to tell us the real problem your trying to solve and we give you a solution that doesn't require listening on node insertion events.

Comment: @Raynos I thought I've said it in "context" section. Though IMO general questions "how to do X" are more valuable for SO in long run then highly specific questions "how to solve my specific problem".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Massive Warning:** [DOMMutationEvents](http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/DOM-Level-3-Events/html/DOM3-Events.html#events-mutationevents) as defined in DOM level 3 are deprecated.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMNodeInserted", function (ev) {
  var node = ev.target;
  if (careAbout(node)) {
    runCode(ev);
  }
});
```

The `DOMNodeInserted` event is documented in [DOM events level 2](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-mutationevents).

Of course browser support is mediocre.

The only way to emulate this in non-compliant browsers is polling the entire DOM for whether the tree has changed and firing events by hand. This is also know as *expensive as hell*.

**But your real problem:**

> Modifying that JS code is highly undesirable

You have bad, ugly, unmaintainable code. Ignoring it isn't going to solve the problem. Stepping around it isn't going to make it go away. The best thing to do is to refactor, refactor, refactor.

Comment: Thanks, take a look at my "update". :P

I've heard it doesn't work at IE at all? And besides, w3c documentation marks it as deprecated?...

Comment: IE9 still doesn't support mutation events. Damn great. I thought the browser would be finally conforming to specs after so many iterations.

Comment: of course you're correct, but that bad, ugly, unmaintainable code wasn't written by me and refactoring is not always feasible.

Comment: @cheshire it's always feasible, however it's probably a world of hurt and not desirable. That bad code is never going to magically go away, either you deal with it or some other sucker deals with it.