# detecting "element was created" in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have several textboxes that are all of the same css class MyClass. I'm creating HTML at runtime. I'm wondering how to detect that a new MyClass textbox was added to the DOM.

I'd like something like this:

```
$('.MyClass').wascreated(function () {
//do something
});
```

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: why can't you add another class to the one that you create with jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Livequery seems to do this (I haven't tested the plugin). I found this on Stackoverflow: [Is there a jquery event that fires when a new node is inserted into the dom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3900151/is-there-a-jquery-event-that-fires-when-a-new-node-is-inserted-into-the-dom)

```
$('.MyClass').livequery(function() {
  alert('.myClass added to dom');
});
```

> If you pass it just a callback function like above, it'll run for each
>   new element it finds, both initially and as they're added.

Livequery can be found here: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery

Comment: I'm plug-in-adverse; any way to do this without a plug-in?

Comment: I would just run whatever code is necessary on the element in the same place I add the element to the DOM: `$('<div class="MyClass"></div>').appendTo('#container').whatever();`

Comment: I already have something like this. I'm looking to remove the "do something" function from the functions that are creating the textboxes.

Comment: Here's a discussion on this topic on the jQuery Core Dev Forum: https://forum.jquery.com/topic/is-there-a-jquery-onaddedtodom-event. I remember reading that discussion so I searched the whole forum and several topics came up: https://forum.jquery.com/search/domnodeinserted

Answer (score 0):

I would either add an extra class to the newly created items or add data.

Adding an extra class would be prefered since this can be easily selected with standard jQuery selectors.

To use data to select an item you would need to either add a extended selector 'plugin', write your own or loop through all items with class `MyClass` and check if the data attribute exists.

Comment: Why would I need to add an EXTRA class?

Comment: @frenchie: I might have misunderstood your question. I thought there were already elements with class `MyClass` on the page and new ones were added dynamically. And you want to find out which ones were added dynamically. Can you please clarify your question for me so I can update my answer?

Comment: No, some textboxes are not on the page; they get added later as the result of an ajax call. They are of class MyClass. I could, at the moment I'm creating them, do the "do something" but the problem is that there are several places in the code that add these textboxes. So for the moment, when I create the HTML, I run the "do something" function. Now, I realize it'd be better to remove this call from all the functions that create the HTML and have the "do something" function be triggered whenever I add the HTML, regardless of which function does the job.