# Progressive enhancement - not hiding elements with CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, graceful-degradation

I often find myself showing/hiding elements with jQuery, for example a simple tabbed content area where the first tab is visible and the others are not until they are displayed with the javascript. I know it's not good practice to hide the initially hidden ones using CSS (display: none) and then showing the correct ones with JS as non-JS users will never see a thing. So by default I show all and then hide the relevant ones with JS.

In doing this though, the hidden elements will load and then only hide when document is ready. How can I stop this happening? Is there a way of doing this in a way that will degrade gracefully but also not have elements appearing whilst loading, and then promptly disappearing as this looks a bit shoddy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a few thoughts...

If you don't mind jQuery being littered all over the page as opposed to being all in a separate file, you can call $('#divToHide').hide(); immediately after the element appears. Not very good practice though. Although it depends on the use case, if you are largely a designer/themer creating a 5 page brochure site, you should choose what is right for you!

Or if you're a bit more of a techie, you might like to mess around with `.live()/.livequery()` and catch the element's insertion with JS and hide is straight away. See this post [Is there a jquery event that fires when a new node is inserted into the dom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3900151/is-there-a-jquery-event-that-fires-when-a-new-node-is-inserted-into-the-dom)

Comment: I fancy myself as a bit of an aspiring techie (ha!) so will have a look at the live functions you mention. thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, the way that Javascript works, <del>this doesn't seem to be possible. There will *always* be a fraction of a second between the first rendered frame and by the time the JavaScript to hide the element gets executed</del> [I was wrong about that, jQuery seems to be able to do that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12090702/1311454). So, CSS is the best means for this. Luckily, you can add an alternate CSS stylesheet within an infamous `<noscript>` tag:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #jquery-thing {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
<noscript>
    <style type="text/css">
        #jquery-thing {
            display: block !important;
        }
    </style>
</noscript>
```

Here's the JSFiddle link:
http://jsfiddle.net/kylewlacy/dbWuc/

Comment: Not entirely true as you can use `jQuery`'s `livequery` to intercept a node being added (and modify it there), but your solution is a good one. I like that this approach gives you an easy way of setting up a separate style sheet for all the CSS you want to be different between script and no-script browsers.

Comment: That's interesting... I didn't know jQuery could do that!

Comment: thanks for that, the css option looks like a good fallback option