# Ember Pre4: How to check if an outlet is already connected?

Tags: ember.js

How can i check wether an outlet is already connected in my application template? In renderTemplate() I want to check wether the outlet actually needs to be connected or not (for performance reasons). The final code should look something similar to this:

```
renderTemplate: function(controller, model) {
    var isMyOutletConnected =  //how to do that?

    if(!isMyOutletConnected){
        this.render('someTemplate', {   // the template to render
          into: 'application',          // the template to render into
          outlet: 'someOutlet',       // the name of the outlet in that template
          controller: "someController"  // the controller to use for the template
        });
    }
}
```

I tried to use the container to lookup the application view  via: `container.lookup("view:application)`
but this instantiated a new view instead of returning the existing one.

Comment: Ember already does this for you. It will not re-render the view if you're transitioning to the same view. Nor will it create another controller, since controllers behave like singletons any way. If it is performance issues then you should leave it well alone, because in adding a check, you're actually increasing the work that your application is having to do when transitioning.

Comment: This is not true actually. I increased the performance substantially by using the solution, i posted. If you look at the code of render(), you will see, that this code always involves the complete teardown of existing outlets, although nothing has changed. This could be alleviated in other ways, but checking the existing outlets is one possible approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your input. This is the solution i came up with:

1 - **Creating a view registry for my singleton views.** View registry resides in the Application instance and its properties are set by the views in didInsertElement.

```
var App = Ember.Application.create({
    viewRegistry : {
        applicationView : null
    }
});

App.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName : 'application',
    didInsertElement : function(){
        App.set("viewRegistry.applicationView", this);
    }
});
```

2 - Now i can **access this registry to check for connected outlets** in my routes:

```
isOutletOfApplicationViewConnected : function(outletName){
    var applicationView = App.viewRegistry.applicationView;
    if(applicationView){
        return applicationView.get("_outlets." + outletName) != undefined;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
},
renderTemplate: function(controller, model) {
    var isMyOutletConnected =  this.isOutletOfApplicationViewConnected("someOutlet");

    if(!isMyOutletConnected){
        this.render('someTemplate', {   // the template to render
          into: 'application',          // the template to render into
          outlet: 'someOutlet',       // the name of the outlet in that template
          controller: "someController"  // the controller to use for the template
        });
    }
}
```

This solution could be more generic, since the method "isOutletOfApplicationViewConnected" is hardwired to my application view, but this is a good beginning and works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Jquery` plugin `livequery` to register a callback when your element is inserted into the dom. This can be done in the view itself

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3900151/is-there-a-jquery-event-that-fires-when-a-new-node-is-inserted-into-the-dom)