# How to hide a div whenever another div is displayed on the screen.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a helpSection that is displayed by default. When the user searches for results, the page reloads and the searchResults should be displayed where the help section is located and the help section set to display:none.

I would like to have some jQuery that searches the page and determines if the helpSection is on the screen or not. If the searchResults are being displayed, the helpSection should disappear.

I have tried various methods and none of them worked. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you post your markup and what you have treid?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better so use server side script to determine what to display based on search params?

Comment: Show some of what you have tried, then we will be able to better help you.

Answer (score 1):

Like this :

```
if($('#yourElement').is(':visible')) 
{
    $('#yourOtherElement').hide();
}
```

If you want to show it instead, you can use show(), like this :

```
$('#yourOtherElement').show();
```

However, if this is something that is determined on page load, it would be smarter to define this using your server-side language.

Comment: He want's to hide the div.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have only one help section on your page.

**Imperative approach:**
So you could solve this problem by using getElementById to retreive your help section element.
If you don't get an element returned it's not appended to the dom, otherwise check the display attribute.

**Event based approach (check browser restrictions):**
If you just remove and append the help section to the dom on demand you could bind dom insertion and removal to trigger the visibility of the other element.
Here is a related post where the event binding is discussed 
[Is there a jquery event that fires when a new node is inserted into the dom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3900151/is-there-a-jquery-event-that-fires-when-a-new-node-is-inserted-into-the-dom)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your HTML markup, you could possibly do it with CSS only.

CSS

```
#searchResults + #helpSection {
    display: none;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="searchResults">Search search search</div>
<div id="helpSection">Help help help</div>
```

On <kbd>[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/9erxV/)</kbd>

See what happens when you remove:

```
<div id="searchResults">Search search search</div>
```