# Increasing the id of new <li> elements only created by orderd list <ol>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-lists

I want to give the increasing id to the new  li elemnts which are automatically created by ol list

```
<div id="txtarea" contenteditable="true">Some text</div>
var html2 = "<div class='steps'><ol><li class='personid' id=''><a href='url-here'>Link Text </a></li></ol><div>";
$("#txtarea").html(html2);
```

**Note:** The li elements must be  automatically  cretaed by ol list and not by manually(By for or while loop)

Here is the js fiddle.Please firstly create the new li element in the jsfiddle.New element will be automatically created  because of ol.Then uyou will see.the id of both li will be same

http://jsfiddle.net/younis764/rWcKu/4/

I want to give increasing  id to each new li element automatically created by ol list.Plz help

Comment: What you mean is : "My list is editable, press enter to create new items.".

Comment: Updated : http://stackoverflow.com/a/20259055/1636522, no dom queries nor loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With consideration to `contenteditable`: http://jsfiddle.net/rWcKu/10/ (updated from rev 9)

Same idea as below, except it is done on the existing element within the `DOMNodeInserted` event handler.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMNodeInserted", function(event){
  var element = event.target;
  if (element.tagName == 'LI') {
    var $el = $(element);
    var maxId = 0;
    $el.siblings().each( function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        if ( id > maxId ) {
            maxId = id;
        }
    });
    $el.attr('id',++maxId);
  }
});
```

---

here's an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rWcKu/8/

The idea is to get the last li's id, parse as int, and increment. Also use the previous li as a template and simply replace its contents (`.clone(true)`) - its classes, events, data, etc. will be cloned as well. Then place the new content (replacing the originally cloned).

Finally, wrap it into a function call where you pass the html you want to insert. This could be called manually, within an event handler, or in a loop of some sort... cheers!

Here's the beef:

```
function addLi(newHtml) {
    var $lastLi = $('#txtarea ol li').last();
    var lastId = $lastLi.attr('id')||0;
    var $clone = $lastLi.clone(true);
    $clone.attr('id',++lastId).html(newHtml);
    $lastLi.after($clone);
}
```

And the usage:

```
addLi('<a href="#">Link text 2</a>');
addLi('<a href="#">Link text 3</a>');
```

It assumes at least one li exists, and that the id attribute is numeric (not mixed type, although this could be retro-fitted with a little `.attr('id')` value parsing).

Comment: create the new li by pressing enter and you will see the ID will be the same

Comment: Thanks.its working.Can it be done with any other approach as document.addEventListener is becoming obsolete and also having compatibility issues

Comment: @user1452376 there's a [jquery plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/livequery/) called [livequery](https://github.com/hazzik/livequery/) that should do the trick. also see [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3900151/is-there-a-jquery-event-that-fires-when-a-new-node-is-inserted-into-the-dom) and note that elements can only be added via jquery in order for livequery to catch the dom insertion.

Comment: @user1452376 It's not working. I've tried the fiddle simply by pressing enter two times, both newly added items have an id of value 1. Anyway, you can't create an id based on the previous item : press enter, select previous li, press enter again.

Comment: @wared how about now? finding the largest id in the sibling list and incrementing, updated fiddle (also updated in answer): http://jsfiddle.net/rWcKu/10/

Answer (score 0):

```
var i=0;// set your value 

var html2 = "<div class='steps ' ><ol ><li class='personid'  id='"+(++i)+"' ><a href='url-here' >Link Text </a></li></ol><div>";

$("#txtarea").html(html2);
```

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rWcKu/6/)**

Comment: This approach is wrong and will not work.  Whenever a new node is create again the i value will be initialized back to 0.  So same `id` will be generated for all `li`s.  To check inspect the li that are newly generated.

Comment: Please check in console log ,the id of the li elements is still sAME.

Comment: @user1452376 in demo it seems it add only one time

Answer (score 0):

i have just modified your code bit i hope this might help you
 please check

```
var html2 = "<div class='steps ' ><ol ><li class='personid'  id='' ><a href='url-here' >Link Text </a></li></ol><div>";
$("#txtarea").html(html2);
var html2 = "<div class='steps ' ><ol ></ol><div>";
for(i=1;i<10;i++)
{
    var newli="<li id='"+i+"' >link text"+i+"</li>";
    $("#txtarea .steps ol").append(newli);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have slightly modified your code for clarity (http://jsfiddle.net/wared/fsQZ2/) :

```
var uid = function (uid) {
    return function () {
        return 'item-' + (++uid);
    };
}(0);

document.addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted', function(event){
    var el = event.target;
    if ((el.tagName + '').toLowerCase() === 'li') {
        el.setAttribute('id', uid());
    }
});

$('#txtarea').html(
    '<ol><li id="' + uid() + '">Some text</li></ol>'
);
```

`uid()` returns an id with a number increasing on each call :

```
uid(); // "item-1"
uid(); // "item-2"
```