# How to get jQuery to keep checking for an element that might get created later?

Tags: jquery, ajax, greasemonkey

I'm trying to make a Greasemonkey script to hide a really annoying div, on a website, that pops up after a few seconds. Neither of these works:

```
$("#flyin").hide();
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#flyin").hide();
});
```

I assume it's because the `#flyin` div is not created, yet.  How do I tell jQuery to keep on looking for this div, maybe every n seconds, so I can hide it?

When I try to hide a non js, regular old div that is always present on the page, it works.

Comment: you can use [setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setInterval) to keep checking it.. or use [mutation observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

Comment: `setInterval(function(){ $("#flyin").hide();}, 500);` Works.  I couldnt get mutationobserver working.

Comment: but once the element is removed you will have to clear the timer... else the jquery code will put additional load ...

Comment: Seems to be the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3900151/is-there-a-jquery-event-that-fires-when-a-new-node-is-inserted-into-the-dom (for more ideas)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's [a utility for that (waitForKeyElements)](https://gist.github.com/2625891).

Your **whole script** would simply be:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _YOUR_SCRIPT_NAME
// @include  http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js
// @require  https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
/*- The @grant directive is needed to work around a design change
    introduced in GM 1.0.   It restores the sandbox.
*/
waitForKeyElements ("#flyin", hideFlyin);

function hideFlyin (jNode) {
    jNode.hide ();
}
```

Or, if the node only appears once per page load and the pages are not wholly changed via AJAX, use:

```
//-- Unload after one run.
waitForKeyElements ("#flyin", hideFlyin, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
(function () {
    var $el = $("#flyin").hide();
    //the element is not already created
    if (!$el.length) {
        //create an interval to keep checking for the presents of the element
        var timer = setInterval(function () {
            var $el = $("#flyin").hide();
            //if the element is already created, there is no need to keep running the timer so clear it
            if ($el.length) {
                clearInterval(timer);
            }
        }, 500);
    }
})();
```