# jQuery - How to check if class is loaded - in a lightbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

on my website there is lightbox. 
With jQuery I can access nearly everything in the main page.
But when I click on the link for the lightbox I have no more access to any element inside that lightbox.

I found a workaround with this:

```
$('.lightbox').click(function () {
    var request = $(document)
        .find('.captcha')
        .data('src') || '';
});
```

But that isn't so nice to use "document".
Anyway that works.

But now ...
I want to check if the lightbox is loaded and add a class to my pictures.
Something like this:

```
$(document).find('.thumbs')
    .find('a:first-child')
    .addClass('active');
```

The problem is I don't know how check if that class or lightbox is loaded.
With this

```
$(document).on('load', '.lightbox-window', function(){
    console.log('lightbox loaded');
});
```

I don't get a response. Even when I use the "click"-Event it doesn't work.

Comment: which lightbox are you using..?

Comment: Try jQuery `hasClass()` Method to find the class

Answer (score 0):

In your lightbox-click function, just toggle a boolean.

```
var lightboxOpen = false;

$('.lightbox').click(function () {
  lightboxOpen = !lightboxOpen; // Reverse boolean, false = true, true = false

  if (lightboxOpen)
  {
    // Add class
  }
  else
  {
    // Remove class
  }
});
```

Would that suffice?

Answer (score 0):

What about [livequery](http://plugins.jquery.com/livequery/) plugin?

```
$('.lightbox-window').livequery(function(){
    // lightbox loaded
}, function(){
    // lightbox closed
});
```

From answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/3900157/1856120