# Fixed footer and outerheight(true) return value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having problems implementing a variable-footer script in jquery.
(But [in JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vpontin/4gaxtwm7/) oddly i'm not having experienced any problem).

Codes:
index.htm

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />

        <title>Footer Test</title>

        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

        <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
        <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->        
    </head>

    <body>
        <nav id="site_navbar" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Habilitar navegação</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">LOGO</a>
                </div>
                <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <header id="site_header">

        </header>
        <main id="site_content">
            <div class="container">
                <h1>TEST</h1>
                <div id="debug_data"></div>
                <p>Test Line</p>
                <p>Test Line</p>
                <p>Test Line</p>
                <p>Test Line</p>
                <p>Test Line</p>
                <p>Test Line</p>
                <p>Test Line</p>
                <p>Test Line</p>
                <p>Test Line</p>
                <p>Test Line</p>
                <p>FINAL LINE!</p>
            </div>
        </main>
        <footer id="site_footer">
            <div class="container">
                <p class="muted credit">Adaptable Footer (or not)</p>
            </div>          
        </footer>

        <!-- jQuery -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Footer Fix -->
        <script src="js/footer_fix.js"></script>
        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

style.css

```
#site_header
{
    padding-top: 70px;
}

#site_content
{
    height: auto;
}

#site_footer
{
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    width: 100%;
}
#site_footer .container
{
    padding: 20px;  
}
```

and footer.js

```
function footer_fix(jQuery)
{
    // Variáveis
    var altura_viewport = $(window).height();
    var altura_conteudo = $('#site_content').outerHeight(true) + $('#site_header').outerHeight(true);   
    var altura_rodape = $('#site_footer').outerHeight(true);

    $('#debug_data').html("");

    $('#debug_data').append("<p>Header height : " + $('#site_header').outerHeight(true) + "px</p>");

    $('#debug_data').append("<p>#site_content height : " + $('#site_content').outerHeight(true) + "px</p>");

    $('#debug_data').append("<p>Total content height (header+#site_content sum) - 'altura_conteudo' value:" + altura_conteudo + "px</p>");

    $('#debug_data').append("<p>Expected value for total content height (header+#site_content sum) - raw element values " + $('#site_header').outerHeight(true) + "px + " + $('#site_content').outerHeight(true) + "px</p>");

    $('#debug_data').append("<p>Viewport window height: " + altura_viewport + "px</p>");

    $('#debug_data').append("<p>Footer height: " + altura_rodape + "ps</p>");

    // Se a altura da viewport (mais o tamanho do footer) forem maiores que o tamanho da altra do conteúdo (ou seja, sobrar espaço)
    if (altura_conteudo > (altura_viewport-altura_rodape))
    {
        $('#site_footer').css('position','static');
    }
    else
    {
        $('#site_footer').css('position','fixed');
        /* $('#site_footer').css('bottom','0px'); */
        $('#site_footer').css('top',altura_viewport-$('#site_footer').outerHeight());
    }
    $('#debug_data').append("<p>Position property > " + $('#site_footer').css('position') + "</p>");
    // PARA FIXAR O FOOTER NA PARTE INFERIOR DA PAGINA

}


$(document).ready(footer_fix);
$(window).resize(footer_fix);
```

Well, the issue is the following: When the page loads or is resized, the function "footer_fix" is called; It calculate if the size of content is smaller than the size of viewport minus footer size.
So if true, this applies the "position:fixed" CSS rule and sets the "top" to size of viewport minus the footer height.

But that's not working as expected. Strangely (to me, i'm not experienced with jquery), the outerheight is passing unexpected values, and because this a miscalculation occurs and sometimes the footer is fixed even if the content is larger than viewport-footer size.

[Here](http://puu.sh/hX35d/bd60b549ab.jpg) is a print explaining the behaviour.

EDIT: In fact, the footer_fix function works properly when i resize the window, but gives me the undesired behaviour in `$(document).ready`. Can it be related?

So, where i failed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic-Height sticky footer (for Bootstrap; jQuery "hack" accepted)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30255792/dynamic-height-sticky-footer-for-bootstrap-jquery-hack-accepted)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a hunch, but that `#debug_data` div you're creating starts with zero `<p>` tags, then you end up inserting 6 of them later via javascript, *after* you've already calculated the height of `#site_content`. Unless the `#debug_data` div was positioned outside the flow of the document with something like `position:absolute`, this would mean that the height calculated when you call

```
$('#site_content').outerHeight(true)
```

...does not reflect the actual height of the document by the time you call:

```
 if (altura_conteudo > (altura_viewport-altura_rodape))
```

...because you've already altered the height by `append`ing those extra `<p>` tags! This would explain why your code functions as expected on a resize -- at that point there are always 6 `<p>` tags present on the page at the time the height is calculated.

If this is the case, a fix might be absolutely positioning the debug div.

Comment: Whoa! Thank you so much! I can't believe i've made such error! Shame on me!
So, is there a way to detect such jquery/javascript line addings in an event? And how about an textarea resize (if needed, i can open another question)?

Comment: No worries, it happens. As for your question, check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3900151/is-there-a-jquery-event-that-fires-when-a-new-node-is-inserted-into-the-dom) but be careful, the event that's marked in the correct answer `DOMNodeInserted ` is actually deprecated. You might consider window.MutationObserver though browser support is not great.

Answer (score 0):

Take height:auto; out of your #site_content style, and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: Doesn't change anything.

Comment: I edited the question to add a note: that behaviour only occour when i call the footer_fix in `$(document).ready()`. When i resize the window (and then the function is called again in `$(window).resize()`), it functions properly.